# Python expected else after if statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement, list-comprehension

Im trying to make a one liner function that removes all instances of b in a, so for example

```
array_diff([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 2])
```

should return

```
[1, 3, 4, 6]
```

This gives the error "expected 'else' after 'if' expression:

```
def array_diff(a, b):
return [a[x] if a[x] not in b for x in range(len(a))]
```

Comment: That's not an `if` statement; it's a conditional expression. They share the same keywords, but `else` is not optional in a conditional expression.

Comment: try this: `return [a[x]  for x in range(len(a)) if a[x] not in b]`

Comment: make b a set so that the comparison is in O(1).

Comment: There is no good one-liner for this.  Do it in 2 lines?

Comment: The filter expression that *follows* the `for` clause of a list comprehension is yet *another* use of the `if` keyword that is neither an `if` statement nor a conditional expression.

Comment: You don't need the integer indexing either... `return [v for v in a if v not in b]` (`a` and `b` should probably have more descriptive names...)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your list comprehension

Try the below:

```
def array_diff(a, b):
    return [a[x] for x in range(len(a)) if a[x] not in b]
```

Comment: Why iterate a range just to index an iterable? Iterate the iterable directly.

Answer (score 0):

In list comprehensions, the part before `for` has to be an expression the evaluates to a value. A ternary operator expression such as `a[x] if a[x] not in b else None` will do so. However, without the `else` part, it's no longer evaluating to anything. If you don't want an else, you have to put the `if` at the very end, such as `[value for value in a if value not in b]`.

Basically, everything before `for` should be something you could stick in a for-loop.

For instance, this works:

```
for value in a:
    value
```

This works:

```
for value in a:
    value if value not in b else None
```

This works:

```
for value in a:
    if value not in b:
         value
```

But this doesn't work:

```
for value in a:
    value if value not in b
```

Your original code is being interpreted as that last one, so it doesn't work.